# Passing JSON data to array inside a class (Alamofire + SwiftyJSON)

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire, swifty-json

I have an `APIManager` singleton

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class APIManager{

let url = "http://myapilink"
static let sharedInstance = APIManager()
var json = JSON()

    func getProgramSessions(program: Int, tokenCode: String, onCompletion: (JSON) -> Void){
    let parameters = ["id" : id, "tokenCode" : tokenCode] as [String : Any]

        Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default)
            .responseJSON { response in                
                guard let dataValue = response.result.value else { return }
                json = JSON(dataValue)
        } OnCompetion (json)

    }
```

A data class called `UserObject`

```
import Foundation
import SwiftyJSON

class UserObject {
    var user_no = Int()
    var user_link = String()

    required init(json: JSON) {
        self.user_no = json["user_no"].intValue
        self.user_link = json["user_link"].stringValue
    }
}
```

I'm seeing optional data in Alamofire response

```
Optional(<__NSSingleObjectArrayI 0x600000010750>(
{
user_no = 100;
"user_link" = somelink;
}
)
```

And when i try to call Singleton to fetch API data and then parse a json into an array based on UserObject class - i get an empty array.

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var id = 0;
        var items = [UserObject]()
        var tokenCode = "sometokencode";

        func addDummyData() {
        APIManager.sharedInstance.getProgramSessions(id:1, tokenCode: tokenCode, onCompletion: { (json: JSON) in
            items.append(ProgrammsClass(json: JSON(json["session_no"].intValue)))
        }) }
        addDummyData()
            }

    }
```

Comment: You are using post as method. Do you want to send or retrieve ? What doesn't mean that you can't retrieve anything using the post method but it is uncommon to use it this way. You can try the api for example by using postman to check the result.

Comment: May be your JSON(json["session_no"].intValue) doesnt able to extract json , make sure is it working user optional chaining for that

Comment: You forgot to call your onCompletion: (JSON)

Comment: @koropok i've added the onCompetion handler to the end of the method - the json is returning, but it's empty.

Comment: I've changed JSONEncoding to URLEncoding in the alamofire request method and started receiving data, but unfortunately, i still cannot parse it.

Comment: I've updated the question description accordingly.

Comment: `json = JSON(dataValue) } OnCompetion (json)` should be `json = `JSON(dataValue); OnCompetion (json)}`. Also, don't add `func addDummyData(){}` inside `func viewdidLoad()` put it as the same level outside it.

Comment: @Larme that really helped! Thank you!